# How do i set an OnSelectionChange to my Tab in JFX

Tags: java, tabs, selection, jfxpanel

I have managed to create a JFoenix tabpane on initialization. However, i do not know how to set certain actions to happen when my tabs are being selected. Below is my code!

```
            tabPanel = new JFXTabPane();
            tabPanel.setPrefSize(440, 50);


            tab = new Tab(); 
            tab.setText("My Events");

            tab2 = new Tab(); 
            tab2.setText("Categories");

            tab3 = new Tab(); 
            tab3.setText("Suggested Events");
            tab3.setId("suggestedEventsTab");




            tabPanel.getTabs().add(tab);
            tabPanel.getTabs().add(tab2);
            tabPanel.getTabs().add(tab3);



            VBox tabBox = new VBox(); 
            tabBox.setPrefSize(446, 100);



            Pane tabPane = new Pane(); 
            tabPane.setPrefSize(450, 100);


            VBox.setMargin(tabPanel, new Insets(33 , 0 , 17 , 0));


            tabBox.getChildren().add(tabPanel);
            tabPane.getChildren().add(tabBox);

            TopPane.getChildren().add(tabPane);

            SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = tabPanel.getSelectionModel();
```

//

Thank you in advance! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add a ChangeListener to listen for ChangeEvents

[JavaFX TabPane: How to listen to selection changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522686/javafx-tabpane-how-to-listen-to-selection-changes)

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningforSelectedTabChanges.htm

Comment: Ok it works but i do not understand the code! Is it ok if you break it down a little bit for me! I am still new to java! Haha thanks in advance

Comment: If you didn't understand the tutorial/code example, I doubt I will be able to explain it any better.  Essentially, you can add a listener object to a component, etc. and it will listen for certain events to be triggered by that component.  Listeners are actually interfaces, meaning their methods are not implemented, therefore you must override the listener's methods with the functionality you desire for each type of action the listener can detect.