# How does one call a method on the changing of a Tab in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx, tabs, listener, fxml

Ok so here is what i am trying to do: I have a page called 'SettingsPage'. Now, in this page i Have a tabPane with 3 tabs; users, buttons, and sales. Buttons and Users both have tables which need to be populated with data before they are viewed by the user. When I was first making the program I just used a 'initialize' method to populate the user table on the opening of 'SettingsPage'. However, now that I am beginning to try and populate the buttons table, I am encountering a memory error because now there is too much data to be loaded at once together.

So, I though a good solution to this would be to make an Event method that is called whenever a certain tab is opened. I am using SceneBuilder atm, and what seemed to be the equivalent of this was onSelectionChanged, however I can't seem to use this as you would use 'methodEg(ActionEvent event)...'. So my question is, how can ensure that a method will be called on the opening of a certain tab.

For example, when 'buttonTab' is clicked, the 'populateButtonTable' method is called.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522686/javafx-tabpane-how-to-listen-to-selection-changes) answer your question ?

Comment: "I can't seem to use this" Why not? What happens when you try?

Comment: @James_D it says it doesn't exists. Whenever I put ActionEvent or EventManager or methods like that it gives a prompt to import them, then I can use them in that class, but for onSelectionChanged  tried a ton of different combinations and nothings existed

Comment: @c0der i think it does, ill try it out later and let you know

Comment: Show the code you have tried.

Comment: @James_D dw I figured it out. I used a listener that checks if there has been a tab change, then goes through an if statement to check which one has been been selected, then from there it calls the specific methods.

I also figured out im kinda retarded because it turns out the reason i kept running out of space if because i accidentally created an infinite loop in one of my methods

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this was this code:

And if anyone asks why I didn't use .isSelected()... I did, it for some reason didn't work, but what I have done below does, so I dunno...

'''

```
@FXML public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){


   tabs.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> ov, Tab t, Tab t1) 
                {                        
                    if (tabs.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == ExampleTab)
                    {
                        //do whatever
                    }      
                }
             }
    );
```

Comment: without context (such a [mcve]) this isn't that helpful for future readers .. you might consider adding the context which should have been in your question, btw :)

Comment: @kleopatra well I actually wrote the context out in my question, I just didn't show the code because there was no point. If i showed the code i had it wouldn't have added any value because all there would have been is showing some data filling and variable initialization. The same goes for here, why bother showing code to initialize a tab? Like what?

What kind of context are you looking for?

Comment: actually, you didn't ;) And when asking for debugging help, you __must__ provide a reproducible code example, otherwise the question is not answerable. This here is just base listener code (and not really good, being ill-formatted, oldish style eventhandler vs. lambda, not following java naming conventions) - in which way could it be helpful to anybody having read and understood a basic tutorial?