# JavaFX: How do I get a specific tab to perform an action

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I am a high school student who's new to Java. I'm trying to create my own simple web browser using Java Fx and I ran into a problem. I have a dedicated tab named "+" and I want this to create a new tab when I press it

This is the main class:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            VBox root = (VBox)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,600);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is the main controller:

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

public class MainController{

    @FXML
    private VBox mainWindow;

    @FXML
    private VBox topPanel;

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;

    @FXML
    private Tab addTab;

    @FXML
    private HBox topBrowserPane;

    @FXML
    private Button backBtn;

    @FXML
    private Button fowardBtn;

    @FXML
    private TextField addressBar;

    @FXML
    private Button refreshBtn;

    @FXML
    private MenuButton settingsBtn;

    @FXML
    private WebView web;

    @FXML
    void getText(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void goBack(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void goFoward(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void refresh(ActionEvent event) {

    }
}
```

And this is my fxml for my scenebuilder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
    <?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>
    
    <VBox fx:id="mainWindow" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="620.0" prefWidth="785.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController">
        <children>
            <VBox fx:id="topPanel" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="785.0">
                <children>
                    <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="785.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
                        <tabs>
                            <Tab text="New Tab" />
                            <Tab fx:id="addTab" closable="false" text="+" />
                        </tabs>
                    </TabPane>
                    <HBox fx:id="topBrowserPane" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="785.0">
                        <children>
                            <Button fx:id="backBtn" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goBack" text="&lt;-" />
                            <Button fx:id="fowardBtn" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goFoward" text="-&gt;" />
                            <TextField fx:id="addressBar" onAction="#getText" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="541.0" promptText="Enter web address" />
                            <Button fx:id="refreshBtn" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#refresh" text="Refresh" />
                            <MenuButton fx:id="settingsBtn" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="31.0" text="...">
                                <items>
                                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Settings" />
                                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Track Site" />
                                </items>
                            </MenuButton>
                        </children>
                    </HBox>
                </children>
            </VBox>
          <WebView fx:id="web" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="780.0" />
        </children>
    </VBox>
```

Comment: what's the problem, exactly? don't see you trying _anything_ ..

Comment: i tried the @FXML and then void addTab(ActionEvent Event) for my tab but I got errors with command so I kinda knew that that wasn't how I make an action listener for the tab

Comment: why do expect an ActionEvent working with a tab? Please read and understand the api doc (tab has no notion of action) and learn how that fxml relates to that api. Anyway, an example (you read the referenced help page, didn't you :) _has to_ contain what you tried and at the same time _must not_ contain anything unrelated (all the empty methods and unrelated buttons/menus are just noise). That said: to achieve your goal, you have implement it yourself - either with a hack similar to Abras answer or by a custom skin.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

All GUI applications are event driven. An event is a user action. You need to listen for the user action that selects the tab with the `+` as its text. Refer to this question (and answer): [JavaFX TabPane: How to listen to selection changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522686/javafx-tabpane-how-to-listen-to-selection-changes)

I'm guessing that when the user selects the `+` tab, you actually want to insert a new tab between the `+` tab and the one before it. The below code does that. Note that you need to add the below method to class `MainController`. (Notes after the code.)

```
public void initialize() {
    SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = tabPane.getSelectionModel();
    ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Tab> selectedItemProperty = selectionModel.selectedItemProperty();
    selectedItemProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observable,
                            Tab oldTab,
                            Tab newTab) {
            if (newTab != null) {
                String text = newTab.getText();
                if ("+".equals(text)) {
                    ObservableList<Tab> tabs = tabPane.getTabs();
                    int count = tabs.size();
                    int index = count - 1;
                    tabs.remove(index);
                    tabs.add(new Tab("New Tab"));
                    tabs.add(new Tab("+"));
                    tabPane.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Note that the code is more verbose than it needs to be. I hope it makes it easier for you to understand it.

The tabs of the `TabPane` are stored in a list. When you add a tab to the list, it gets added to the end. There is no *insert* method. Hence I remove the last tab, i.e. the one with the `+`. Then I add a new tab and finally I re-add the tab with the `+`.

I also clear the selection because once you select a tab, it stays selected so when you click on the `+` tab twice in succession, the selection does not change and hence the listener is not executed. I also assume that you want to add a new tab each time you click on the `+` tab.

Comment: hmm .. looks fishy (no wonder, with a muddy question and me not near my ide to try ;) - a) selection != clicking b) clearselection on a model which should enforce exactly one item selected is not really specified c) remove/add is .. not needed: what's wrong with are(int, Tab)?

Comment: .. add (int, Tab) .. darn auto-correction ;)

Comment: thank you... I'm trying to understand what's going on haha